# Transaction check error when installing oracle on Centos OS

Tags: oracle, centos7

I am trying to install oracle with the following command on centos 7.5.

```
sudo yum install oracle-database-server-12cR2-preinstall -y
```

However, I am getting the following errors.

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-default.preset from install of redhat-release-server-1:7.6-4.0.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /etc/os-release from install of oraclelinux-release-7:7.6-1.0.15.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /etc/redhat-release from install of oraclelinux-release-7:7.6-1.0.15.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /etc/rpm/macros.dist from install of oraclelinux-release-7:7.6-1.0.15.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /etc/system-release from install of oraclelinux-release-7:7.6-1.0.15.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /etc/system-release-cpe from install of oraclelinux-release-7:7.6-1.0.15.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Could anybody help me?

Thanks
Shuja